# Intellij IDEA - DB Navigator - reveal password

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I use "DB navigator" plugin(https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator/)  for my Intellij IDEA Community version quite some time and am very satisfied.

I want to know the password of my DB connection saved in the plugin. They are saved, they are there, but I cannot share it with my teammates.

Even all the IDEA passwords are set to be stored in the system keyring, I don't find them in `seahorse`, i.e., "Passwords and Keyrings" application in my Ubuntu.

Where are they?

Comment: Hm. 1k views and no upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found it in

```
<project_root>/.idea/dbnavigator.xml
```

search your connection name, and you will see sth like this:

```xml
    <connection id="e208f307-8c08-45d5-93fd-958c1d68d049" active="true">
        <database>
          <name value="UAT" />
          <description value="" />
          <database-type value="ORACLE" />
          <config-type value="BASIC" />
          <database-version value="11.2" />
          <driver-source value="BUILTIN" />
          <driver-library value="" />
          <driver value="" />
          <url-type value="SERVICE" />
          <host value="some-host" />
          <port value="1523" />
          <database value="APP_DB" />
          <type value="USER_PASSWORD" />
          <user value="admin" />
          <deprecated-pwd value="<base64-encoded-password>" />
        </database>
        ...
    </connection>
```

So, I tried to base64 decoded them... and it works...

Please, if the author sees this, please **don't encrypt it** in the future versions; I need them to be in my local so that I don't have to ask my teammates again; too shy am I. Please take into consideration that I created the tag `db-navigator` for the first time while asking this question, so that ppl around the world could gather together with love of this plugin.

And, any coder reading this: please ignore this file in Git, as it contains sensitive data.